# How to convert timestamp to a 5-6digit number?

Tags: oracle, timestamp, data-conversion

I have a tiemstamp date like this `12/31/1999 12:00:00.000000 AM`
I want it to turn into this `121999`. Basically omit the day.

If the month is between January-September, the number should be 5 digits(IE.21998), October to December should be 6 digits(IE.102014)

I have something that works but it looks like a caveman. Is there a better way?

```
   SELECT  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(EX_DATE,'MMDDYYYY'),1,2))
            ||TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(EX_DATE,'MMDDYYYY'),5)) AS  EX_DATE
    FROM TOL
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want

```
SELECT to_char( ex_date, 'fmMMYYYY' ) as ex_date
  FROM tol
```

if you want a 5 or 6 character string or

```
SELECT to_number( to_char( ex_date, 'fmMMYYYY' )) as ex_date
  FROM tol
```

if you want a number.

Of course, I would hesitate to call either a string or a number `ex_date`.  And I would hesitate to call a column of type `timestamp` something like `ex_date` that implies that the data type is really a `date`.  I would either use something that identifies the data type properly, i.e. `ex_ts` for a `timestamp`, or I would change the data type to match the name of the column.